# Accidentally shift+del bea_home

Tags: oracle, weblogic, data-recovery

I accidentally shift+del my bea_home directory and lost all files and folders inside it.

I found out that I can still connect to the database but couldn't really start a weblogic domain since they were all gone.

I tried to use file recovery tools but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question?  Assuming that you don't have a backup and don't have software that will restore the deleted files, you're looking at reinstalling WebLogic.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't able to ask the question. But you seem to provide the answer I was looking for. Thanks.